# python 2.7 and segmentation error for gdal

Tags: python-2.7, gdal

I am a newbie in python and have a code that uses third part bindings in gdal to open and process satellite images. How best can i catch a segmentation error. I have read information on the web with no specific answer. When I try to run the script it gives me an error. segmentation fault(core dumped). I also use (gdb) to trace where the error occurs and it is when gdal tries to open the image. the error emanates from the following.
    try:
            hDataset = gdal.Open( pszFilename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )
        except:
            if hDataset is None:
               print("gdalinfo failed - unable to open '%s'." % pszFilename )

Comment: Can you simplify your script and post a minimal example which shows the segmentation fault?

Comment: try:
            hDataset = gdal.Open( pszFilename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )
        except:
            if hDataset is None: